# Solution to a definite integral

Tags: integration

I have the following definite integral.

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}  \left(\frac{1}{\left(1-B\cos(x)\right)^2}\right)dx$$

I tried inputting into Wolfram and it exceeded the computation time.  Anyone know what or how to get a solution (if there is one).

Comment: What is $B$ in here?

Comment: B is a constant

Comment: Wolfram gets an answer quickly: $2\pi/(1-B^2)^{3/2},$ provided (of course) $|B|\lt 1.$

Comment: This could be solved maybe by Residue Theorem

Comment: @whuber - Thanks, but I just tried again with Wolfram and standard computation time was exceeded.  Did you input the formula in a different way than what I show in my original post? Or is there a way that I tell Wolfram that B < 1, which it is by the way.

Comment: One trick is to specify strong assumptions that are still likely to produce a general result.  I used `Integrate[1 / (1 - Cos[x] b)^2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> 0 < b < 1/2]`.